# Fixing / treating wood surface in kitchen

Tags: repair, wood, woodworking, kitchen-counters, wet

I recently moved into a new house and the wooden kitchen work surface looks like it has some marks / damage where it has either been wet for an extended period of time or something has been left on it (or both). The area that looks the worst is by the sink so I am assuming it is water / damp related. There is also a portion of the surface in the corner that has been wet since I moved in (few days ago) - I have made sure not to put anything on top of it in the hope it dries but not sure if there is anything I need to do? Anyway from some research before I moved in I have bought a pot of Osmo Topoil which I had intended to treat it with (I knew it needed treatment of some kind but couldn't see the marks / damage when I viewed it) but I think I probably need to do something about the areas of concern before treating it with oil? There are also marks from cups / mugs which I assume can just be sanded away as well? Any advice you can given would be greatly appreciated! From other research I've done I'm hoping it might just need to be sanded down and then oiled (hopefully nothing more than that!)

Attached is a picture of probably the worst bit (next to the sink), but the bit behind the tap handles is probably as bad as this as well (can't seem to upload multiple photos). Thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: I would suggest this may be a better fit at the [woodworking.se] sister site, as there is vast knowledge of finishing and refinishing there, especially when it comes to wet areas.

Comment: Heck, it's probably already got an answer there...